# How do I know if seeds are growing?

Tags: houseplants, containers, growth, peppers, repotting

I bought some "aji dulce" (peppers) seeds from home depot,and I planted two of them in a pot, but I have no idea if these seeds are growing since they are so small.

Instead of planting them in a pot and waiting for them to grow, is there another way to know if they're growing?

I was wondering if there's a way to "monitor" their growth, so that once I know the seed sprouted, I can move it to a pot with soil.

I was thinking of the technique [used with avocados](http://www.marysrosaries.com/collaboration/images/thumb/b/bd/Growing_Avocado_From_Seed.JPG/789px-Growing_Avocado_From_Seed.JPG), but for much smaller seeds.

Answer (score 1):

The information you gave is a bit vague but I'll try to help. Germination can take from 7 to 14 days, I would look more towards 12 days. A common mistake made is to plant them to deep, such small seeds should have no more than a "sprinkling" of soil over them. One quarter inch maximum, remember too not all the seeds are 100% viable. Putting all your hopes on 2 seeds seems to be asking for a lot.
Germination rates can be as low as 50%. Keep the sowed seeds in a warm spot also, direct sunlight isn't a requirement but 70 to 80 degrees Fahrenheit is. The top covering of soil must be kept damp at all times, I use a mister.
If you really want to see the progress of any seeds you start you can also use the paper towel method. This involves just putting the seeds between two layers of paper towels, keep damp at all times, and keep in a warm place. Then you eventually transplant them very shallow, directly in soil at the first signs of germination.
Above all remember not to deep, keep moist and warm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you're saying that I should have used more seeds?

Comment: I used two seeds because I'm using a 4" pot, so I thought that using more would be too many.

Comment: For a 4" pot how many seeds should I plant?

Comment: I guess all I meant by that was your not giving your self very good chances, it's entirely possible neither of the 2 are viable (will sprout) I just think your limiting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard and fast rule growing plants from seed, small starts.  Never plant plants or seed in a pot with too much soil.  Growing baby plants in pots is very different than growing from seed in the body of soil in your garden.

I never grow seeds unless I have 1" diameter by 2" deep start cells and sterilized potting soil.  Within a few weeks under grow lights, ventilation, no fertilizer, using only a spray bottle to dampen the soil hosting the seed...keeping that soil moist not wet, you will see roots coming out of the little pot.  Then those starts need to be transplanted into 3" pots.  Then a little balanced fertilizer is necessary. Water more deeply but allow to dry out a bit before more water.

The soil in a start cell as well as the soil in the next up potting should be FIRMED, gently but firmly firmed.  One seed per cell.  Wait until you see what happens with the first up potting!  No fertilizer until the first up potting or 2nd 3rd set of leaves.

2 seeds in a 4 inch pot is far from ideal but should have produced two plants.  Which is okay.  The widest part of the seed times 3 is the depth for that seed.

Pepper plants should germinate and show their cotyledons within a week maybe a few days more but otherwise, the seeds probably damped off (rotted).

Most people water the soil and seed way too much.